# J2ME - code signing using verisign Intermediate CA

Tags: java-me, code-signing, jar-signing, verisign

I want to sign the J2ME midlet using verisign intermediate CA. Does any one know how to do that or any one succeed with verisign code signing. Please help me with the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thawte is better than Verisign in many ways. So buying Thawte and using it is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Verisign class 3 code signing certificate, which you can then use to sign with as normal using KeyTool

However you need to check which devices you wish to deploy to, as common as a Verisign certificate is, the root certificate is not present on all phones! unfortunately this means if you sign the application you will be unable to install on those devices where the root certificate is not present.

The most ubiquitous root certificate on the phones is the one provided by the UTI for which you will need to look into the Java verified process.